# Who should pay for iOS Developer Program?

Tags: payment-terms, price

I'm a freelancer and I recently got an iOS development job. This is the first time I've developed an iOS app, and I remembered that Apple charges $99 a year for publishing for the App Store.

Now, should I have quoted them for that in the original price? Should I tell them they'll have to pay for that, or should I deduct it from my own pay and create the account for myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If client is the one who will be distributing the application then he/she must pay for it, because he will be the one getting money for the application. 
Client can add you as developer to his team, so you'll just need a developer account(without subscription).

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how to tell the client this? I don't think they realize they'll have to pay for this and I didn't account for it in the original bid.

Comment: Just tell them that money application will earn will go to the account used to publish the app to App Store. I'm sure they don't want money to go through you and your account. And you'll have to pay taxes etc. In this case they basically don't own the application. Anyway this is not a one time payment so it's not supposed that you pay   something every year for each application you develop.

Comment: Just tell me "can you give me access to your ios developer account". They will either give you the access or tell you they don't have it. In later case, reply back with a link to where they can register account and offer your help if they get stuck in the process.